# SQL Date/Time Manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, schedule

So I have a set of Hours for a particular set of days (lets call it a schedule), that schedule describes the general pattern.  However, occasionally there are what I will call exceptions where the schedule is grown or restricted.

For example:

Schedule for Monday is 7:00 AM - 4:00 PM, 5:00 PM - 9:00 PM

Exceptions for this next Monday in particular: 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM

Is it possible to manipulate the hours in the SQL Query to return 7:00 AM - 4:00 PM, 5:00 - 6:00PM, and 7:00 PM - 9:00 PM.  I realize it is probably possible with a temp table and about three different queries, but I was hoping to do it more elegantly.

Another option might be to do this all in C# logic... I will really appreciate any help with this scheduling problem.

Source Tables (please note I am still Open to changing the structure if necessary)

```
Schedule - A user can set up a named schedule
Id
Name


ScheduleDates - Describes the dates range(s) a schedule is active
Id
ScheduleId
StartDate
EndDate


ScheduleEntries - Describe the schedule that describes most 
of the dates in the schedule
ScheduleId
StartTime
EndTime
DayId (Describes which day of the week)


Exception
Id
Reason
StartTime
EndTime
```

Comment: Describe your source table(s).

Comment: Is your fields just date or datetime? I'm asking because there is no need for the table ScheduleEntries if your fields is datetime. You already have the day on startdate

Comment: Is an exception meant to be only for a specific ScheduleEntry?  If so I would add a Id field to the ScheduleEntry table, and a foreign key reference to ScheduleId in Exception.  I would also add a DayId field to Exception.  You would then be able to left join ScheduleEntries on Exception, and use it as an override.

Comment: It looks like a collections of CTEs might be able to handle it. Could you edit your question to include the data types for each column and some sample input and result rows? Do you want to generate results for a specific schedule or all schedules?

Comment: Originally, I wanted Exceptions to not be schedule specific but if that will remove the need for a CTE I might opt for that approach - at least at the moment I believe our MAXRECURSION is set to only 100 so long schedules might have issues with a CTE (or other people that have used a CTE in our environment are doing something wrong).

Comment: [MAXRECURSION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) is a query hint that defaults to 100. If you specify `MAXRECURSION 0` in the query then the recursion is unlimited.

Comment: Alright that makes sense - is it common practice to set it to 0 when you are making use of a CTE?

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Comment: The solution is still in the works, but I will post the general idea of what I ended up with.  If you think I am doing something silly feel free to comment =).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with for my specific case I decided that I would just like all the information back so that I can inform the user something about the hours are special.

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '12-25-2013'
DECLARE @end DATE = '1-31-2014'

;WITH [DateIt] AS -- Explodes the dates between start and end inclusive
(
    SELECT
        @start AS [sd],
        DATENAME(dw, @start) AS [dt],
        DATEPART(dw, @start) AS [dw]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, sd),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 1, sd)) AS [dt],
        DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 1, sd)) AS [dw]
    FROM
        [DateIt] [di]
    WHERE
        sd < @end
)

SELECT --DISTINCT -- May need distinct here
    [di].[sd] AS [Date],
    --[di].[dw] AS [DayNumber],
    --[di].[dt] AS [DayName],

    [s].[Id] AS [ScheduleId],
    [s].[Name] AS [ScheduleName],

    [se].[LocationId],

    [se].[StartTime],
    [se].[EndTime],

    0 AS [ExceptionState] -- Normal Schedule
FROM
    [DateIt] [di]
    INNER JOIN [campusHours].[ScheduleEntries] [se] ON [di].[dw] = [se].[DayId]
    INNER JOIN [campusHours].[Schedule] [s] ON [s].[Id] = [se].[ScheduleId]
    --INNER JOIN [campusHours].[ScheduleDates] [sd] ON [sd].[ScheduleId] = [s].[Id]
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            [campusHours].[ScheduleDates] sd
        WHERE
            -- Choose the valid schedule
            [di].[sd] BETWEEN sd.[StartDate] AND sd.[EndDate]
            AND
            -- Don't take days from a different schedule
            s.[Id] = sd.[ScheduleId]
    )
UNION ALL -- We are going to add in the exceptions
SELECT
    [di].[sd] AS [Date],
    --[di].[dw] AS [DayNumber],
    --[di].[dt] AS [DayName],

    0 AS [ScheduleId], -- Represents that we aren't a schedule, could use NULL if you like
    'Exception' AS [ScheduleName],

    [e].[LocationId],

    [e].[StartTime],
    [e].[EndTime],

    CASE WHEN [e].[IsContraction] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS [ExceptionState] -- 1 is contraction, 2 is extension
FROM
    [DateIt] [di]
    INNER JOIN [campusHours].[Exception] [e] ON [di].[sd] = [e].[StartDate]
ORDER BY
    [di].[sd], [LocationId], [se].[StartTime]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put your suggestions as in what you have already figured, we can definitely make on that. Still my suggestion would be to make a proc and use Getdate function and create a algo to check whether that time falls under that your exception. Rest I am sure you can figure. :)